# typescript issue when using union and Record in combination

Tags: typescript

I get a compile error but if I remove the "| string" then it works. Shouldn't  tsc detect which type here aplies?

```
interface Window { 
    a: {
      [key: string]: Record<string, any> | string;
    };
    b: {
      [key: string]: Record<string, any>;
    };
}

window.a.key.prop = "text"; // <-- error
window.b.key.prop = "text";
```

[demo in TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.4#code/FASwdgLgpgTgZgQwMZQAQHVwBMD2B3VAb1WFTNQQC4jTyyBtAaygE9qBnCGcAcwF1qAJShIcMLAB5O3MDwA0FMCwB8qAD6ppvANy0yAX110ARtUJ7yTVhy68BqYaPFTbshQiXKj5Q8H3BgPGx8ADoEEOYWEIAHGBxo1ABeVAAiaAAPCBTtVAB6XNQJAFoi1Fg4mEDgvBDjCNYYuITktKhM7KA)

Comment: You must check IF it's not a string before accessing a prop

Comment: How should TS know whether `window.a.key` is a `Record<string, any>` so that you *can* use `.prop` or a `string` so that you *can not* use `.prop`?

Comment: Without a [mre] that initializes `a` and `b` it certainly seems like the error is correct.  If the code above is prefaced by `window.a = {key: "oops"}` then `window.a.key.prop = "text"` will result in a runtime error, and this error is what the compiler is trying to warn you about.  Do you want an answer that explains how the compiler is doing the right thing here?  Or do you want to [edit] your question with enough code that demonstrates why you think the compiler should behave differently?

Comment: hmm, ok that makes sense.